# Разделение разрядов в числе

Tags: php

Есть цены в формате - 4000, 200, 40000, 100000, 1000000 и т.д. Нужно привести их в более читабельный вид - т.е. поставить пробел после каждой 3 цифры с конца - 4 000, 200, 40 000, 100 000, 1 000 000 ... Как это можно сделать на php ?

Comment: ну не регуляркой же.... ё-моё...... http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php

Comment: @AK ваш ход? :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Я - пас. )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string number_format (float $number, int $decimals = 0, string $dec_point = ".", string $thousands_sep = ",");
```

`$number` - Число

`$decimals`  - Кол-во цифр после запятой

`$dec_point` - Разделитель десятичной части

`$thousands_sep` - Разделитель между тысячами

```
number_format(4000,0,'',' '); //4 000
number_format(1000000, 2, '.',' '); //1 0000 000.00
```